# Rearranging VARMA(1,1)

Tags: arima

Can 
$$
X_t - a X_{t-1} = Z_t + Z_{t-1}
$$
be written with recursion as 
$$
X_t - a^2 X_{t-2} = Z_t + (1-a) Z_{t-1}
$$
where $a =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1/3 \\
    1/3 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$?

I wasn't sure of how to find the autocovariance when the MA(1) did not have a companion matrix.

Answer (score 1):

No, it generally cannot, unless $Z_{t-2} = 0$ for all $t$: Define the lag operator $L$ such that $LX_t = X_{t-1}$, and similarly for $Z_t$. Then the equation you start with above can be rewritten as a lag polynomial of form
\begin{align}
 (1-aL)X_t = (1-L)Z_t.
\end{align}
Using the third binomial formula, it is obvious that $(1+aL)(1-aL) = (1-a^2L^2)$, and as $(1-a^2L^2)X_t = X_t - a^2X_{t-2}$ by definition of the lag operator, one can now write
\begin{align}
 (1+aL)(1-aL)X_t & = (1+aL)(1-L)Z_t\\
(1-a^2L^2)X_t  & =  (1 + (a-1)L - aL^2)Z_t \\
X_t - a^2X_{t-2} & =  Z_t + (a-1)Z_{t-1} - aZ_{t-2}.
\end{align}
So in particular, $X_t - a^2X_{t-2}  =  Z_t + (1-a)Z_{t-1}$ if and only if $(a-1)Z_{t-1} - aZ_{t-2} = (1-a)Z_{t-1}$, which obviously only holds if $Z_{t-2} = 0$.

Comment: (+1) well the last part could hold for other situations, but $\{Z_t\}$ wouldn't stationary.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean! That is actually a very good point - so you are saying that defining $W_{t-1} = (1-a)Z_{t-1}$, one could write the last part as $2W_{t-1} = -a Z_{t-2}$, which would then imply that we have the relationship $-(2 \cdot a)^{-1}W_{t-1} = Z_{t-2}$, i.e. $-2(1-a)a^{-1}Z_{t-1} = Z_{t-2}$. Now noticing that $a^{-1}Z_{t-1}  = 3 Z_{t-1} $  and that $-2(1-a) = ((2,-2/3), (-2/3, 2))$, it becomes clear that indeed as you say, the resulting process $\{Z_t\}$ is non-stationary. Thanks, that was a great remark!